# Powershell move files to a new folder that are not still writing to the source folder

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that's moving files from a source directory over to a target directory every 15 minutes. Files of around 1 meg are moving into the source directory by an SFTP server... so the files can be written at anytime by the SFTP clients.

The Move-Item command is moving files, however it seems that it's moving them without making sure the file isn't still being written (in-use?).

I need some help coming up with a way to write the files from the source to the target and make sure the entire file gets to the target. Anyone run across this issue before with Powershell?

I searched and was able to find a few functions that said they solved the problem but when I tried them out I wasn't seeing the same results.

Existing PowerShell script is below:

```
Move-Item "E:\SFTP_Server\UserFolder\*.*" "H:\TargetFolder\" -Verbose -Force *>&1 | Out-File -FilePath E:\Powershell_Scripts\LOGS\MoveFilesToTarget-$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss).txt
```

Comment: If the application writing to the file is doing so by continuously reopening it and not locking it, PowerShell is free to move it. It's not like it can know that, in a short while, the file will be written to again. You'll have to do something like get the `LastWriteTime` of the file and move it only if it's "old enough" for clients to effectively be done with it.

Comment: Does the application writing to these files create a temp-file like Office products do?  `~partialname.docx`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up cobbling together a few things and got this working as I wanted it. Basically I'm looping through the files and checking the length of the file once... then waiting a second and checking the length of the file again to see if it's changed. This seems to be working well. Here's a copy of the script incase it helps anyone in the future!

```
$logfile ="H:\WriteTest\LogFile_$(get-date -format `"yyyyMMdd_hhmmsstt`").txt"

function log($string, $color)
{
if ($Color -eq $null) {$color = "white"}
write-host $string -foregroundcolor $color
$string | out-file -Filepath $logfile -append
}

$SourcePath = "E:\SFTP_Server\UserFolder\"
$TargetPath = "H:\TargetFolder\"
$Stuff = Get-ChildItem "$SourcePath\*.*" | select name, fullname


ForEach($I in $Stuff){
log "Starting to process $I.name" green

$newfile = $TargetPath + $I.name

$LastLength = 1
$NewLength = (Get-Item $I.fullname).length

while ($NewLength -ne $LastLength) {
    $LastLength = $NewLength
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    log "Waiting 1 Second" green
    $NewLength = (Get-Item $I.fullname).length
    log "Current File Length = $NewLength" green
}
log "File Not In Use - Ready To Move!" green
Move-Item $I.fullname $TargetPath


}
```